# How to show single blade.php file in another blade.php file as a component/portion

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-cards

I don't know this is the right way to ask this. But here is my question and if anyone know please answer.

I have two blade files in my project. I'll name them **1 & 2**. 1st blade file only contains a chart. I'm trying to show that chart in my 2nd blade file. But the requirement is, I want to show the 1st blade file chart in a small bootstrap card view in the second blade file. So is that possible.?  if it is, does anyone know how to do that.?
*Please let me know if my question is unclear.*

*If there is no way to do this or if it is hard, then I want to know how to show a chart in a (bootstrap)card view using considering table data. (if there is a source for that it will be very helpful*)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `@include` blade directive for this.

let's suppose your `chart.blade.php` component is in the `view/includes` folder, in your 2nd blade file you use it in this way:

`@include('includes.chart')`

Comment: This should be the answer. But when I'm trying this, there is another issue coming from my code in my side. I'll try to fix it and try this again. Thanks a lot.